Suddenly applied discrete complex exponential inputs and convolution
I am reading the textbook Discrete-Time Signal Processing by Oppenheim & Schafer.
I am confused about how to get $y[n]$.
By discrete-time convolution, we have
$$y[n]=x[n]\ast h[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n-k]h[k]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}h[k]e^{j\omega(n-k)}u[n-k]=\bigg(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}h[k]e^{-j\omega k}u[n-k]\bigg)e^{j\omega n}$$
Up to this point, I have no idea how to get $y[n]$ in the textbook. Since we have no idea how $h[k]$ looks like, how could we say that $y[n]=0$ for $n<0$?  Moreover, how to deal with $u[n-k]$?
Could anyone let me know to get $y[n]$ from my last step?   Thanks!


The text uses the term "impulse response". Do you have a definition for that? Because that determines the structure of $h$.

@RollenS.D'Souza Definition is under the assumption of linear time-invariance $T{{\delta[n-k]}}=h[n-k]$.

Presumably, $u$ is the unit step function, so $x[n] = 0$ for $n < 0.$ Take the convolution,
$$
y[n]=x[n]\star h[n] = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} x[n - k]\,h[k]
$$
and split it into two sums, breaking it at $k = n$,
$$
y[n]=x[n]\star h[n] = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{n} x[n - k]\,h[k] + \sum_{k = n 
 + 1}^{\infty} x[n - k]\,h[k].
$$
If you look carefully at the right hand side, you will see that in the right hand sum we have that $n - k \leq n - (n + 1) < 0 .$ So $x[n-k]$ is evaluated only in negative time in that term. Thus, the $x$'s in the right hand sum are all zeros, meaning we can eliminate them,
$$
y[n] = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{n} x[n - k]\,h[k].
$$
Since $h$ is the impulse response of the system $y$, we know that $h[k] = 0$ for $k < 0.$ Thus,
$$
y[n] = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} x[n - k]\,h[k].
$$
From which, if you carefully follow the splitting of sums, you can then draw the conclusion that $y[n] = 0$ for $n < 0$: In negative time case, the first summation is eliminated fully in that second step.
Then direct substitution will take you to the finish line for the final expression in the non-zero sample times.

How could you say "since $h$ is impulse response of $y$, we know $h[k]=0$ for $k<0$?  It is only hold for the causal systems. Well, if you assume that natural/physical system is causal; then I can accept it.

@sleevechen yes. Causality appears in the impulse response characteristics. Without causality the formula doesnt hold
